# How can I detect if my chrome packaged app is running or closed?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

[**Deprecated**] Since Google decided to [phase out Chrome packaged app](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html), this question is no longer valid.

My Chrome packaged app is running in background by setting permission **"background"** in [manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) file. I have a listener onUpdateAvailable which is written in **background.js**.

Now Whenever I get event on this listener, I want to check whether my app is active and visible or only running in the background.

This is specially needed because if app is active and visible, some cleanup code will execute and then reload. If app is not visible and only running in the background, I simply need to reload the app. This is what I need:

```
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener( function () {
if (  ) { // my app is visible
    // clean-up code
    chrome.runtime.reload();
} else { // app is not visible
    chrome.runtime.reload();
}
} );
```

Comment: developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-getAll

Comment: I tried this but the problem is I don't get the app window details by this method in background.js. I get such details in other js files only.

Comment: chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage

Comment: @kzahel chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage is for chrome extensions. I am specifically talking about chrome packaged app. This doesn't work in chrome packaged app has chrome app doesn't differentiate between background page and other pages.

Comment: It's for packaged apps, too. You might want to look at "app lifecycle" docs. Not sure why you aren't able to app.window.getAll to do what you want, though (should help you determine whether your app is "active")